# Multiple image swap with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, image

I needed to make on my website page with thumbs of my categories. When user hover on the thumb it will change few images. So I found this tutorial and so far is work but it crops the images. How can be done without to crop them?

```
jQuery(function($){

        // Cycle plugin
        $('.slides').cycle({
            fx:     'none',
            speed:   1000,
            timeout: 200
        }).cycle("pause");

        /* Pause  play on hover */
        $('.slideshow-block').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('.slides').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
        });

    });
```

[Here is the website with tutorial](http://buildinternet.com/2011/09/cycle-through-images-on-hover-with-jquery/)

[Here is the DEMO on **Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d45vhcq4/)

The images on the demo are big and you can see how they are cropped.

Comment: Your fiddle-link is not working.

Comment: Edited. Sorry about that.. I've added some code also because didn't let me to save the edit without..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please add the below css and check.

```
.slides img{width:100%; }
```

Comment: Thank's for your replay. Here is the updated version and it's the same [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d45vhcq4/1/)

Comment: @Goro I am not seeing the changes in fiddle

Comment: Please add width 100% for img not for .slides

Comment: Yes, with `.slides img { width: 100% }` working fine. I've added it to `.slides{}` first time.. Thank's again for your help!